# How to work with double bit codes and doubleToLongBits() in Java?

Tags: java, double

I was able to get the binary code of double numbers:

```
Double d = 1.5E12;
long l = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
String bin = Long.toBinaryString(l);
System.out.println(bin);
System.out.println(bin.length());
```

However, the resulting code doesn't behave like a double bitcode, it doesn't make any sense:

```
1.5E12   --> 100001001110101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000 (length: 63)
-1.5E12  --> 1100001001110101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000 (length: 64)
1.5E-12  --> 11110101111010011000110110011001000001110001001101111100011010 (length: 62)
-1.5E-12 --> 1011110101111010011000110110011001000001110001001101111100011010 (length: 64)
```

I tried to understand those number by grouping them:

```
1.5E12   -->     10000100111  0101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000
-1.5E12  --> 1   10000100111  0101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000
1.5E-12  -->   (0)1111010111  1010011000110110011001000001110001001101111100011010
-1.5E-12 --> 1   01111010111  1010011000110110011001000001110001001101111100011010
```

First of all it adds/removes a bit for the minus signs (that's a bad thing...speaking of parsers). But even more the exponent shows very dubious numbers: E.g. 10000100111 is supposed 1035 (= 1023 + 12) instead of 1063 (1063 - 1023 = 40!), and (0)1111010111 is supposed to be 1011 (= 1023 - 12) instead of 983 (983 - 1023 = -40!).

Does anyone know how to read this double bit code? I.e. how to get the right exponent and the mantisse out of above bit codes?

(An example: How to get the value 1.5E12 back again out of the bit code? 100001001110101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000 --?--> 1.5E12)

**UPDATE:**

Using the mask from the Java API I ended up to get the values like this:

```
static final long SIGN = 0x8000000000000000L;
static final long EXPN = 0x7ff0000000000000L;
static final long SGNF = 0x000fffffffffffffL;

Double d = ...;
long lng = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
String bin = Long.toBinaryString(lng);
long sign = (lng & SIGN) >>> (bin.length()-1);
long expn = (lng & EXPN) >>> 52;
long sgnf = lng & SGNF;
```

And I could easily print it:

```
System.out.println("sign-bin: "+Long.toBinaryString(sign));
System.out.println("expn-bin: "+Long.toBinaryString(expn));
System.out.println("sgnf-bin: "+Long.toBinaryString(sgnf));
System.out.println("sign-string: "+Long.toString(sign));
System.out.println("expn-string: "+Long.toString(expn));
System.out.println("sgnf-string: "+Long.toString(sgnf));
```

With the Double 1.5E12 I got this result:

```
sign-bin: 0
expn-bin: 10000100111
sgnf-bin: 101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000
sign-string: 0
expn-string: 1063
sgnf-string: 1640400372629504
```

Do you know how to get the "real" decimal values out of them? (E.g. 1640400372629504 --> 1.5 and 1063 --> E12)

Comment: Look up IEEE floating point standard for double in Wikipedia.  Your results look good.  Note your method is truncating leading zeros.

Comment: As I said, I expected different values: 1035 instead of 1063, aso. Wikipedia doesn't give me any explanations how to deal with this code...it's probably just a mathematical trick that must be done to transform above bitcode into decimal numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That the 0 for the sign is "missing" is just a number writing convention.

In the decimal system you will write 1067 instead of 0001067, right? This is just wha Java did. Th 0s exist in memory, they are just not displayed, because you don't need them forth number.

---

Also this is a floating point representation of a **binary** number.

If you convert 1.5*10^-12 to a binary number, it will have a lot of 0s at the beginning (I started, but then my paper ended - there are definitely more than 12 0s at the beginning). This binary number is then normalized (so that there is only one 1 before the point) and the exponent of this normalization is used as the exponent. I guess the binary exponent of 1.5*10^-12 is indeed 40.

In other words: the exponent of an IEEE number represents the value 2^exponent, not 10^exponent, like we use it in the decimal system.

---

According to [this page](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/arun/cpre381/ieee754/ie5.html) you will need to multiply each digit of the mantisse with the corresponding power of 2 starting with 2^-1, then 2^-2 and so on and add them up.

Then you use this formula:

> (-1)^(sign bit) * (1+fraction)  * 2^(exponent - bias)

where `fraction` is the number you calculated from the mantisse. 
`exponent` is the decimal representation of the exponent. `bias` depends on your precision, in your case double precision, which means 1023. For single precision it's only 127.

---

You cannot directly convert the binary representation parts (say the binary exponent) to the decimal counterparts (the decimal exponent). At least I don't konw how.

So you will need to convert the complete number to decimal and then split it into the number and its exponent.

Here is the Java code to convert the binary representation to decimal:

```
static final long SIGN = 0x8000000000000000L;
static final long EXPN = 0x7ff0000000000000L;
static final long SGNF = 0x000fffffffffffffL;

public static void main(String[] args){
    Double d = -0.0000000000015;//1500000000000d;
    long lng = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    String bin = Long.toBinaryString(lng);
    long sign = (lng & SIGN) >>> (bin.length()-1);
    long expn = (lng & EXPN) >>> 52;
    long sgnf = lng & SGNF;



    System.out.println("sign-bin: "+Long.toBinaryString(sign));
    System.out.println("expn-bin: "+Long.toBinaryString(expn));
    System.out.println("sgnf-bin: "+Long.toBinaryString(sgnf));
    System.out.println("sign-string: "+Long.toString(sign));
    System.out.println("expn-string: "+Long.toString(expn));
    System.out.println("sgnf-string: "+Long.toString(sgnf));

    String mantisse = Long.toBinaryString(sgnf);
    int pow2 = 2;
    double fraction = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < mantisse.length(); i++){
        if(mantisse.charAt(i) == '1'){
            double curr = 1.0/pow2;
            fraction += Double.isInfinite(curr)? 0: curr;
        }
        //System.out.println(fraction + " " + pow2);
        pow2 <<= 1;
    }

    System.out.println((1+fraction));
    System.out.println("Back to decimal: " + (sign == 1?(-1):1) * (1+fraction) * Math.pow(2, expn - 1023));
}
```

Note that the result is not exactly accurete, since the floating point arithmetics in computers are not accurate and there is a limited sapce in which to store the information.

I dont't know how to extract the number and it's exponent from a double. My best guess is manipulation the String representation linke this:

```
String[] number = Double.toString(dBack).split("E");
System.out.println("Decimal exponent: " + (number.length == 2?number[1]: 1));
System.out.println("Decimal mantisse: " + number[0]);
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: I updated the question, maybe it will help you to provide some Java code?

Comment: Actually, I was searching for a way to convert a binary double number into a decimal double number. Your solution only gives the absolute value of the number, but no decimal double number...as said I need to convert e.g. 1640400372629504 --> 1.5 and 1063 (or e40) --> e12

Comment: Because the question is too complex to be handled here, I decided to accept your answer for god sake ;)

Comment: For info here's the code how to do it: http://docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html

Answer (score 1):

As the Wikipedia page says,value of the number is

[image: expression for IEEE 488 double precision number value] .

So the binary exponent is 1063 - 1023 = 40.   This makes sense because it multiplies the mantissa by 2^40, which is about 10^12 (because 2^10 is about 1000, 2^40 will be 1000^4).  (This method of coding exponents is called zero-offset.  It's used rather than 2s complement because it leads to simpler hardware.)

The mantissa raw bits are  0101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000, so prepending the 1 as the formula above says, we have:

```
1.0101110100111110111101111001100000000000000000000000
```

Now, shifting the binary point 40 places to the right to account for the exponent, we have:

```
10101110100111110111101111001100000000000.000000000000
```

Happily, in decimal this is the integer 1500000000000, exactly what we want.

From this you should be able to get the algorithm.  The first step is to compute the integer part (just as I have done above) and use the standard algorithm for printing integers:

```
i = 0;
while (int_part > 0) {
   digit[i] = int_part % 10
   int_part = int_part / 10
   i = i + 1
}
if (i == 0) return '0'
else reverse digits[0..i-1] and return
```

This leaves the fraction bits.  If there are N bits, then treat them as an N-bit integer and divide by 2^N.  For example, a 1-bit fraction of 1 is 1/2.  You can get decimal digits by implementing long division.  For example binary .11 is 3/4.  Implementing long division, we first get 3*10/4 = 7R2.  Then 2*10/4 = 7R0.  So the decimal digits are .75.  In pseudocode:

```
num = frac_part
den = 2 ^ (number of bits in frac_part)
i = 0
do {
  num = num * 10
  digit[i] = num / den
  num = num % den
  i = i + 1
} while (num != 0)
```

Note these algorithms are conceptual, not practical.  For one thing, they assume arbitrary precision integers.  In practice you don't want this overhead, so calculations are actually done in floating point.  The good old book [Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130224189) by Wirth goes into some detail about how this works.

If you are implementing `printf` or similar library function, the details of base conversion are extremely hairy to get right with good speed. By "right" I mean being able to print a number in base-10 and read that representation back in with perfect confidence that you'll get exactly the same number.  Don't underestimate this problem.

Also, as others have said your Java print routines are just eliding all leading zeros because they're intended for people, and people usually don't care about leading zeros.

Comment: Interesting, the binary shifting, thanks for that! Helped me a lot to understand the hole thing.